# Two SQL queries take a lot of time difference in Presto

Tags: presto

I deployed a presto cluster, 2 workers node. But two SQL queries take a lot of time difference.

```
//sql1: it takes 398.12ms
SELECT count(employee_name) from employee where jobstatus=2;

// sql2: it takes 16.58s
SELECT count(employee_name) from employee where create_time > date_parse('2018-12-20','%Y-%m-%d') and create_time < date_parse('2019-12-20','%Y-%m-%d');
```

I guess sql2 is to load all the data of the employee table into the memory for filtering, and sql1 is directly filtered in the oracle, how to confirm? Or is there another way to locate the cause?

Presto version is 0.147. The `employee` is Oracle table and has 50w data, of which 36 are `jobstatus=2`, `date_parse('2018-12-20', '%Y-%m-%d') and create_time < date_parse('2019-12-20' , '%Y-%m-%d')` has 98. `create_time` and `jobstatus` all is not indexed.

No concurrent support during testing, it is sequential execution

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting Oracle from Presto then those queries will be single threaded (single JDBC connection) from Presto side which means only one worker would be active independent of the cluster size. Hence, whatever performance number you are seeing, that will be coming from the Oracle side.

Based on the given performance number, it seems create_time column is indexed and jobstatus not. Please verify that.

Comment: Thinks for replay, `create_time` and `jobstatus` all is not indexed